# move a row in google spreadsheet based on todays date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to move a row of data from one sheet to another in the same spreadsheet based on a value of today's date.

In column "A", I have a date. I want to move the row if the date entered in column "A" is older than today's date. (it's a flight schedule for aircraft and I want to move flights that have already occured onto a sheet called "Past Flights".) The name of the active sheet is "Flight Schedule".

After the row is moved, I want it to delete off the "Flight Schedule" sheet. I know where to add scripts, but have no idea how to make this happen.

Here is what I have tried. I think on line "If (data.link >1..." data.link isn't the right one to use. But I can't find something for indicating older than todays date.

```
function approveRequests() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
 sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(),
 sheetName = sheet.getName(),
 data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 if (sheetName == "Flight Shedule") {
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange(),
  startRow = range.getRowIndex(),
  numRows = range.getNumRows(),
  numCols = range.getNumColumns()
  if (numCols == 9) {
   if (data.length > 1) {
    var values = range.getValues(),
    nextSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Past Flight"),
    lastRow = nextSheet.getLastRow();
nextSheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1,numRows,3).setValues(values);
sheet.deleteRows(startRow,numRows);
   } 
  } 
 } 
}
```

Any help would be huge!

Thanks!

Comment: I should add this is in Google Sheets.

Comment: If you are asking for specific help about writing the script you will typically get better responses if you post some code that shows what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thanks. I should have thought to add what I have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I will go in with some general tips based on your current code first.

In your function you do a `sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()` which is redundant because you already have `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`.Also I would recommend to avoid this

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
 sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(),
 sheetName = sheet.getName(),
 data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
```

in favour of this:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var sheetName = sheet.getName();
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
```

which is much more easy to read and change without making mistakes.

`data.length` has nothing to do with current date, it will simply be the length of the array. So if you select 1 row of data, it will be `1`, if you select 2 rows it will be `2` etc. `.getValues()` will return an array where `data[row][col]`. What you are looking for is getting the value of the flight time, converting it into a date object (not a google specific thing, just general [javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)). Then use `var now = new Date()` and compare the two.

I would also recommend to re-think your `if` statements. There are a lot of better ways to grab the row data than selecting the row manually and then running the function. You can save a lot of lines of code should you decide to actually make this run automatically, because as it is, it will run only when called manually.

Comment: Thank you. Still getting my chops and this was useful!

Answer (score 0):

This sample is working:

```
function approveRequests() {

  // Initialising
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var scheduleSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Flight Shedule");
  var pastSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Past Flight");
  var lastColumn = scheduleSheet.getLastColumn();

  // Check all values from your "Flight Schedule" sheet
  for(var i = scheduleSheet.getLastRow(); i > 0; i--){

    // Check if the value is a valid date
    var dateCell = scheduleSheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
    if(isValidDate(dateCell)){
      var today = new Date();
      var test = new Date(dateCell);

      // If the value is a valid date and is a past date, we remove it from the sheet to paste on the other sheet
      if(test < today){

        var rangeToMove = scheduleSheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, scheduleSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
        pastSheet.getRange(pastSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, scheduleSheet.getLastColumn()).setValues(rangeToMove);
        scheduleSheet.deleteRow(i);

      }
    }
  }
}

// Check is a valid date
function isValidDate(value) {
  var dateWrapper = new Date(value);
  return !isNaN(dateWrapper.getDate());
}
```

So yes, It's not the optimized solution (cause of the use of several sheet.getRange() method), but it's working and allowing to have a clear code.

Comment: This was very helpful! Gets me heading closer to the right place!